# How to filter not equal to data based on list in cells Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter my data based on a list of criteria. The list of criteria will be maintained on the actual spreadsheet since it needs to be updated by other users in column Z.
 [image]
I tried using an advanced filter, and eventually I was going to implement it in VBA  but it didn't return any values. The size and length columns are intentionally left blank. I want it to return all the data in the table on the left so that none of the words in the table on the right show up.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
Sub createFilter()

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Activate
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="<>*shirt", field:=4, Criteria2:="<>*jean" 'you can repeat this as much you need

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks  but it doesn't compile when there are more than 2 criteria. I also need it to be able to filter out the criteria that is added by other users who do not have access to the macro.

Comment: how will they be able to add more filter? will you insert activex control for that? like an input box and a command button, etc?

Comment: I was hoping to keep the list of criteria in the cells in column Z and filter the data in columns A-D. Is that not feasible? If so do you know another method of filtering multiple "does not contain" criteria?

Comment: sorry, just did a research right now and it's not doable using a filter, you will need to loop through the range and hide rows based on criteria

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the help but I did more research on the advanced filter and now it works.

Comment: that's nice, could you please post your own solution as an answer so i can learn more on filters? it's a pretty fresh topic for me to work on vba

Comment: This thread really helped me with the advanced filter
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/813108-advanced-filtering-multiple-does-not-contain-criteria.html